# Sort two arrays by the values of one array

Tags: sorting, go

What is the idiomatic way to sort two slices by the values defined in one slice, in Go?

I have two slices (for example)

```
a := []int{2, 5, 3, 6, 3}
b := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
```

I want to sort array `a` so that it is in order. Then I want to sort array `b` so that the pairing is consistent.

The result should be

```
a = []int{2, 3, 3, 5, 6}
b = []string{"a", "c", "e", "b", "d"}
```

Note how `(a[i], b[i])` is consistent for each value of `i` before and after sorting.

Comment: You can consider defining a pair struct, constructing a slice of pairs that consist of values from a and b. Sort the slice of pairs and overwrite values in a and b.